# Фреймворк для тестирования JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

Посоветуйте фреймворк(и) для тестирования. Пишу в mean стеке, и нужно тестировать как клиентский код так и серверный.

Немного погуглил и увидел что их довольно много, но разбираться или пробовать каждый сейчас, к сожалению, нету времени.

Спасибо!

Comment: karma + jasmine - очень доволен.

Comment: @vas karma это для клиентского кода. а jasmine для сервернрого ?

Comment: нет, это для клиентской и серверной стороны.